# remove rows having more than one records in an INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to filter out rows having more than one **b.STIME**,  **b.A_PTY_NBR** and **b.B_PTY_NBR**.

```
  SELECT DISTINCT *
  FROM   star_idd a
  INNER JOIN
  star_vendor b
  ON (
  TO_DATE( a."DATES" || a."STIME", 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS' ) BETWEEN TO_DATE(   b."DATES" || b."STIME", 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS' ) - INTERVAL '12' HOUR AND TO_DATE( b."DATES" || b."STIME", 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS' ) + INTERVAL '12' HOUR
  AND b.B_PTY_NBR  = a.TRIM_A_NBR
  AND b.A_PTY_NBR  = a.TRIM_B_NBR )
```

Currently, there are two records in table a that matches 1 record in table b. The tendency is, it will create a same record in table b to match another record in table a. I just need to display only one row.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Please edit your question to include sample data, expected output, and the output you're getting. [If you really want help, create an SQLFiddle with your tables and data set up](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you meant to use `ROW_NUMBER()` function to remove the duplicates like

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT DISTINCT a.*,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY b.STIME ORDER BY b.STIME) rn
  FROM   star_idd a
  INNER JOIN
  star_vendor b
  ON (
  TO_DATE( a."DATES" || a."STIME", 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS' ) BETWEEN TO_DATE(   b."DATES" || b."STIME", 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS' ) - INTERVAL '12' HOUR AND TO_DATE( b."DATES" || b."STIME", 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS' ) + INTERVAL '12' HOUR
  AND b.B_PTY_NBR  = a.TRIM_A_NBR
  AND b.A_PTY_NBR  = a.TRIM_B_NBR)) xx
WHERE rn = 1;
```